# What might be the cause of ffmpeg JPG->MP4 stopping before the last input file?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-7

Here's the output showing 2177 frames converted https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFECI.png. It is ignoring the further 1000-odd frames in the input set.

There's nothing unusual AFAICS about input JPG 2177.

What might cause this? Where should I look for more info?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if numbering isn't perfectly smooth `output02177.jpg` is followed by e.g. `output02179.jpg`, or if `output02178.jpg` is 0-sized.

**Edit**: I just remembered, you're using a very old build of ffmpeg. Upgrade to 4.0 or newer, and change `-r 60` to `-framerate 60`

Comment: Thanks. but numbering is perfectly contiguous here.